# Find specific values from String array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm new to Java/Android development. I need to get the specific values from my string array.

```
String PictureTest[] = {"a.jpg","b.png","c.txt", "d.wav", "e.tga"};
```

This array is diffrent every time. I need to get all values which contain .jpg, .png, .tga and form a new array with them.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(PictureResult));
//It prints "a.jpg, b.png, e.tga"
```

UPD: Thanks everyone for this quick and useful responses!

Comment: Use regex. http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-image-file-extension-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for loop to iterate through the elements in `PictureTest[]` and check if each of them `contains()` the extensions. Use an `ArrayList` or `List` to store the values because the size of an array cannot be modified.

```
String PictureTest[] = {"a.jpg","b.png","c.txt", "d.wav", "e.tga"};
ArrayList<String> PictureResult = new ArrayList<String>;

for(String item : PictureTest) {
    if(item.contains(".jpg") || item.contains(".png") || item.contains(".tga") {
        PictureResult.add(item);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** If you only need to check the file extension at the end, you can use `endsWith()` instead of `contains()`.

Comment: Would it be any better to use item.endsWith()?

Comment: @EricGuan Thanks for the suggestion! Depending on OP's requirements, `endsWith()` may be a better choice. I will add that to the answer...

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way you can iterate over the original array and search for your pattern:

```
List<String> pictureResult = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String picture : PictureTest) {
    //use something like contains or a regex, for example
    if (picture.contains(".jpg"))
        pictureResult.add(picture);
    //etc...
}
```

You get the idea...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you can use Predicates to filter your list. Something like this:

```
public class PredicateTester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String PictureTest[] = {"a.jpg","b.png","c.txt", "d.wav", "e.tga"};
        List<String> filteredList = filterStrings(PictureTest, filter());
        filteredList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static Predicate<String> filter() {
        return p -> p.endsWith(".jpg") || p.endsWith(".png") || p.endsWith(".tga");
    }

    public static List<String> filterStrings (String[] fileNames, Predicate<String> predicate) {
        return Arrays.asList(fileNames).stream().filter( predicate ).collect(Collectors.<String>toList());
    }
}
```